# PHP, mySQL : Set an Array limit \ offset

Tags: php, pagination, limit, offset

Hello Guys how can i set an limit and offset vor an sql Array
im executing an .sql file and write it in `$sql` but i need an offset for paging cause i get the whole data set.

```
public function getSqlDetailsAction()
{
    $fileName = $this->Request()->getParam('fileName');
    $pluginFolder = dirname(dirname(__DIR__));
    $sqlFolder = $pluginFolder . '/SqlFiles/';
    $filePath = $sqlFolder . $fileName;
    $sql = file_get_contents($filePath);
    $sql.=" limit ".$start.", ".$limit;
    $sqlResultList = Shopware()->Db()->query($sql);
    $this->View()->success = true;
    $this->View()->data = $sqlResultList->fetchAll();
}
```

Comment: what's in the sql file?

Comment: select * from table    ! here the request from js backend 'dev/backend/UnSqlReader/getSqlDetails?_dc=1442478815251&fileName=sql2.sql&page=1&start=0&limit=25'

Comment: You have it, **but you dont have a `$start` and `$limit` set** So set those and you are good to go. I would change this line though to  `$sql.=" limit $start,$limit"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you are new to development or amending someone elses code in an environment you are not familiar with or just using SO as free development. So I will code it for you.

```
public function getSqlDetailsAction()
{
    $fileName = $this->Request()->getParam('fileName');
    $start    = $this->Request()->getParam('start');
    $limit    = $this->Request()->getParam('limit');

    $pluginFolder = dirname(dirname(__DIR__));
    $sqlFolder = $pluginFolder . '/SqlFiles/';
    $filePath = $sqlFolder . $fileName;
    $sql = file_get_contents($filePath);
    $sql.=" limit ".$start.", ".$limit;
    $sqlResultList = Shopware()->Db()->query($sql);
    $this->View()->success = true;
    $this->View()->data = $sqlResultList->fetchAll();
}
```

This appears obvious from the info you have given us, but as I see you have a `page=1` in the querystring maybe you intended to do something slightly different and calc the `LIMIT` values from a page number and a lines-per-page mechanism, but thats just a extra F.L.O.C and you should be able to work that out.

Comment: Thank u :) it works fine :D and yes u are right im new with PHP :D